# Labeling for Constraint Logic Programming in prolog

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming, clpfd, labeling

I am currently writing an (exciting!) code in prolog that aims at returning an optimal reforestation plan after defining a certain purpose.

I have now, per grid cell generated a list of possible tree species to plant, and I have designed which grid cells should actually contain trees in a plan and which should be left "blank" (the density of trees also differs per reforestation purpose). I have now come to the point where I am trying to optimize

1. The amount of different species: If pos(1,2) can house *tree_species1*, *tree_species2*, *tree_species3*, and pos(4,10) can house *tree_species2*, *tree_species3* and *tree_species4* I would prefer that different values (e.g. *tree_species1*, *tree_species4* respectively) are assigned to them. However, if this is not possible, I would love for the program to plant two of the same species rather than return "false" (which I think would happen using the "all_different/1" predicate.
2. Which tree is best for which purpose. For example, I would rather plant an Aspen than a White beam for biodiversity. I was thinking of connecting the different tree types to a score (biodiversity_score(Tree, Score)), but am unsure how I can use the CLP functions then to generate a "maximum" function.

I came across "labeling" but failed to see how I can manipulate this to my purpose.

Comment: Please show what you have attempted to program so far.

Comment: Exciting! It sounds like you have a good base to search for solutions, but may need to nail down what it means to optimize it - e.g. 500 cells and 5 different species, 496 cells of one species and 1 of each of the others is "the maximum number of different species" in some sense, but not great. You could count the cells assigned to each species and say none can be more than 15%, or subtract to get the difference and seek a solution which minimizes the differences in amount-of-each-species.

Comment: Similarly, you could make Aspen tree 1 and White Beam tree 2 and arrange the constraint solver to start counting up from 1, so it would prefer Aspens, or you could arrange so solutions must have (count of Aspens) #> (count of White Beams). There are probably other ideas. If you have not seen this video, check it out it goes into some Prolog constraint labelling strategies: https://www.metalevel.at/queens/

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thank you so much :) I have implemented the percentage benchmark to limit the amount of trees, and have ordered the trees for each purpose to. Thanks again for the help!